# AngularJs SPA with master/detail views: a "slow" approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

My app is a simple AngularJS SPA, which is essentially a contacts manager: the master (landing) page is a list of persons, one per row, in a `ng-repeat` loop.
Each person, clicked, shows the details page: a form with many fields.

Currently my router is like this

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    ...
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/persons.html',
      controller: 'PersonsController'
    })
    .when('/details/:personId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/person.html',
      controller: 'PersonsController'
    })
    ...
  });
```

I.e.: one controller for both master ('person**s**') and detail ('person') view, and two separate views (of course).

The link to the `Detail page` on each row in the master view does:

```
$location.path('/detail/' + id);
```

and the `Back to master page` link in the detail view does:

```
$location.path('/');
```

This approach (which is the "institutional" approach, I suppose...) has many drawbacks:

- since my persons list is quite big (300 persons and growing), with one small image for each person, the loading of the master page is very slow (~5 - ~8 seconds), even if I save the `$scope.persons` array in a service, to avoid to resync it from server: the slowness is due to Angular, I suppose (the browser freezes for almost the whole time...). I did not yet try to optimize my code (and reduce the `$watch`es), I know :-), but...
- When returning to master page, the scroll position is lost: the view is shown from the top, which could be very annoying, for the user... :-(

*The question is*:

*Is there a better approach you'd suggest? (for example, just changing the template view, instead to change location...)*

Comment: does DOM rendering is taking time or loading data from ajax and loading it into `img` src is taking time?

Comment: If angular is slow because you're trying to display a list of 300 people, you could add paging, sorting, and searching to the list (which is probably going to be a better option anyways -- I don't think many people want to dig through a list of 300 (and growing...) items to find the one they want

Comment: @pankajparkar: I'm quite sure it's DOM rendering: the browser is freezed (the loading icon stops its rotation, for example): during the AJAX loading of the image and data from server it rotates, and the browsere responds...). More, it happens also for the second loading, when all images are already in the browser's cache (a 304 code is returned from server).

Comment: @Tom: I *do* already have sorting and searching, of course... And the paging could only relieve the problem, not solve it... The question is more "methodological"...

Comment: 300 items should render very fast . What happens if you use a placeholder image? If that doesn't help somethings wrong in the code. Post some controller and view code

Comment: No change with placeholder. it's slow even when when images are cached (read answer to @pankajparkar comment...).

Comment: @charlietfl if the image size is big then its matter

Comment: @pankajparkar: images in master view are small: 96x120 px... More, slowness doesn't change even with**out** images...

Comment: @pankajparkar wasn't just thinking about size... what about 300 x 404's by using `src` instead of `ng-src` for example

Comment: @charlietfl: sorry, I don't get your point...

Comment: Marco...you need to post some code. Something in the code is wrong

Comment: I wouldn't mind posting my code, but it's quite many lines... It should be a too long a process for me to strip it down to be postable here... :-( Though, I'm already quite satisfied, since I think you are saying: "your approach is correct, some detail is wrong"... I just noticed I have ~ 1k watches in my master view... :-( I suppose I will start from there...

Comment: are you creating watches? Most likely wouldn't need to for a simple master/detail

Comment: @MarcoS 1k watchers.Thats huge number.are you creating them dynamically?

Comment: I did not explicitely use any watcher... Just starting to try to understand where do they come from ... :-( and sorry, I made a mistake: they are not 1k, but 13k !!! I forgot to mention my project is an open repository on github (https://github.com/marcolino/escrape)...

Comment: every `{{ .. }}`, `ng-` counts and ng-repeats multiply them, and then automatically add to watchers, look for angular-once, bind-once or angular-js 1.3 's one time binding syntax `{{::variable}}`

Comment: may be change all `{{` to `{{::`, since you using angular1.3.

Comment: @YOU: Thanks! I'll try your suggestion ASAP!!! Didn't know about {{:: syntax... And thanks for looking through my code... :-)

Comment: @YOU: I did just try your '::' suggestion in a test environment, but watchers did fall from ≈300 to ≈70 !!! (if you want to post your comment as answer I'll accept it...). I also found some blog articles about Angular optimizations, that I will try to implement, too... (for example here: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135, http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/)

Comment: Yeah, I even went further and making my own approach like fastest templating engine called doT, [repo](https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA) - [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/dot-dota-handlebar), but my approach is limited to very small set of html tags, and few angular features, and error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `{{ .. }}`, `ng-` counts and `ng-repeats` multiply them, and then automatically add to watchers. So, you need to look for angular-once, bind-once or angular-js 1.3 's one time binding syntax `{{::variable}}`

According to your repository, you using angular 1.3, so you can use angular's one time binding syntax ::, so, you can just try to change `{{` to `{{::` for those you don't really need 2 way binding.